# How to create multiple canvas dynamically(using loop) in angular2

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

I want to create multiple canvas in my component using loop in angular2.

**This is my html**

```
   <div class="masterpage" *ngFor="let x of masterPages" draggable [dragScope]="'masterpage'" [dragData]="x">
        <canvas #myCanvas width="105" height="149" style="background:lightgray;"></canvas>
   </div>
```